# How to add a custom property in UltraTreeNode Collection (Infragistics UltraTree Control)

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics, ultratree

How can I add a custom property in UltraTreeNode collection? using UltraTree Infragistics control 12.x version.

For example:

```
UltraTree MyUltraTree = new UltraTree();
UltraTreeNode MyNode =  new UltraTreeNode();
MyNode.Text = "Caption of My Node";
MyNode.MyCustomProperty = "This is custom property want to Add in Node Collection";
MyUltraTree.Nodes.Add(MyNode);
```

Comment: It's [not sealed](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.1/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinTree.v12.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinTree.UltraTreeNode.html), so you can subclass it. Or you could just use the `Tag` property?

Comment: Right but I need to add many properties. multi vales. If i use tag property it will be hard to handle. However you are right Tag property is ultimately last solution

Answer (score 0):

As stuard wrote you can inherit `UltraTreeNode` like this:

```
public class CustomUltraTreeNode: UltraTreeNode
{
    public string MyCustomPorperty { get; set; }

    public string SomeOtherCustomProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use `CustomUltraTreeNode` instead of `UltraTreeNode` like this:

```
UltraTree MyUltraTree = new UltraTree();
CustomUltraTreeNode MyNode = new CustomUltraTreeNode();
MyNode.Text = "Caption of My Node";
MyNode.MyCustomPorperty = "This is custom property want to Add in Node Collection";
MyNode.SomeOtherCustomProperty = "This is some other custom property";
MyUltraTree.Nodes.Add(MyNode);
```